# Why do rapply and lapply handle NULL differently?

Tags: r, null, lapply

I'm aware that NULL values in lists can sometimes [trip](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-set-components-of-a-list-to-NULL_003f) people up. I'm curious why in a specific instance `lapply` and `rapply` seem to treat `NULL` values differently.

```
l <- list(a = 1, c = NULL, d = 3)

lapply(l,is.null)
$a
[1] FALSE

$c
[1] TRUE

$d
[1] FALSE
```

So far so good. How about if we do the exact same thing with `rapply`?

```
rapply(l, is.null, how = "replace")
$a
[1] FALSE

$c
list()

$d
[1] FALSE
```

This example is very simple and non-recursive, but you see the same behavior in `rapply` with nested lists.

My question is why? If, as advertised in `?rapply`, it is a 'recursive version of lapply', why do they behave so differently in this case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you answered your own question: because it's recursive.

You don't often see this, but `NULL` can actually be used to indicate an empty sequence, because it is the empty `pairlist` (similar to how `()` in Scheme terminates a list. Internally, R is very scheme like).

So, `rapply` recurses into the empty list, but doesn't bother turning it back into a pairlist when it's done; you get a regular empty list.

Actually, `rapply` and `lapply` don't really treat NULL that differently:

```
> lapply(NULL, identity)
list()
```

And you can see in the R source code ([memory.c](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/memory.c)) that this is exactly how pairlists are meant to work:

```
SEXP allocList(int n)
{
    int i;
    SEXP result;
    result = R_NilValue;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result = CONS(R_NilValue, result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out that `NULL` is an empty `pairlist`. So it sounds like you're saying that `rapply` can't (or won't) distinguish between `NULL` and `pairlist()`.

Comment: @joran `identical(pairlist(), NULL)` :)