# What is the difference between NULL and character(0) in R?

Tags: r, null

What is the difference between NULL and character(0) | integer(0) etc?

```
> identical(NULL, character(0))
[1] FALSE

> is.null(integer(0))
[1] FALSE

> str(character(0))
 chr(0) 

> str(NULL)
 NULL
```

In general it seems you can pass `NULL` as parameters into functions, and that an empty vector is generally returned as `character(0)`, `integer(0)`, etc.

Why is this the case?  Come to think of it, is there a test for zero-ness, *a la* `is.integer0`?

Comment: `class(NULL); class(character(0))`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [R Language Definitio](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html)n has this on `NULL`:

> There is a special object called NULL. It is used whenever there is a need to indicate or
>   specify that an object is absent. It should not be confused with a vector or list of zero 
>   length. The NULL object has no type and no modifiable properties. There is only one NULL 
>   object in R, to which all instances refer. To test for NULL use is.null. You cannot set 
>   attributes on NULL.

So by definition `NULL` is very different to zero length vectors. A zero length vector very much **isn't** absent. `NULL` is really a catch-all for something that is absent or not set, but not missing-ness, which is the job of `NA`. There is an exception, the zero-length pairlist, as mentioned by @Owen. The Language Definition states:

> A zero-length pairlist is NULL, as would be expected in Lisp but in contrast to a zero-length list.

which highlights the exception in this case.

To test for a zero-length vector use something like `if(length(foo) == 0L)` for example. And combine that with a class check (`is.character(foo)`) if you want a specific type of zero length vector.

Comment: Though see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170264/why-do-rapply-and-lapply-handle-null-differently for a peculiar similarity.

Comment: @Owen You're correct. I was overlooking that pairlists are not vectors at all, even when they have nonzero length. I've removed my comment to avoid any additional confusion.

Answer (score 11):

The other guys have the right answers, but I want to add a few curiosities.

First, it's not *quite* true that NULL "is used whenever there is a need to indicate or specify that an object is absent" as it says in the doc. There are actually 2 other "no data" values in R (not counting NA, which is not a complete value).

There's "missing", which is used for missing arguments:

> alist(x=)$x

```
> identical(NULL, alist(x=)$x)
[1] FALSE
> y = alist(x=)$x
> y
Error: argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Then there's "unbound", which you can't (AFAIK) access directly, but using C:

```
SEXP getUnbound(void) {
    return R_UnboundValue;
}

> x = .Call("getUnbound")
> x
Error: object 'x' not found
```

Comment: +1 Perhaps what they mean is that `NULL` "is used _by the end user_ to indicate or specify that an object is abset", while R uses other things internally in some cases.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a partial answer, beginning by simply quoting the R Language Definition Guide:

> There is a special object called NULL. It is used whenever there is a
>   need to indicate or specify that an object is absent. It should not be
>   confused with a vector or list of zero length. The NULL object has no
>   type and no modifiable properties. There is only one NULL object in R,
>   to which all instances refer. To test for NULL use is.null. You cannot
>   set attributes on NULL.

I take that to mean that zero length vectors can have attributes, whereas `NULL` cannot:

```
> x <- character(0)
> y <- NULL
> attr(x,"name") <- "nm"
> attr(y,"name") <- "nm"
Error in attr(y, "name") <- "nm" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```