# How to manipulate NULL elements in a nested list?

Tags: r, list

I have a nested list containing NULL elements, and I'd like to replace those with something else.  For example:

```
l <- list(
  NULL,
  1,
  list(
    2,
    NULL,
    list(
      3,
      NULL
    )
  )
)
```

I want to replace the NULL elements with NA.  The natural way to do this is to recursively loop over the list using `rapply`. I tried:

```
rapply(l, function(x) NA, classes = "NULL", how = "replace")
rapply(l, function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x, how = "replace")
```

Unfortunately, neither of these methods work, since `rapply` apparently ignores `NULL` elements.

How can I manipulate the `NULL` elements in a nested list?

Comment: I finally gave up on rapply and use [something which I can predict how it will work](https://github.com/raredd/rawr/blob/master/R/utils.R#L1372-L1381) so `rapply2(l, function(x) if (is.null(x)) NA else x)` would work

Comment: Here is an interesting [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170264/why-do-rapply-and-lapply-handle-null-differently) that talks about this some but doesn't quite answer your question of how to get around the issue.

Comment: at steveb; it is on point. I'm  sorry @Owen doesn't seem to be spending much time here anymore. His posts were always very insightful.

Comment: Basically everyone thought to do the same thing and rewrite their own recursive lapply. A little overburdensome IMHO; perhaps this should exist in base R.

Comment: @rawr  I wonder if you have changed the behavior of `rapply2()` since you wrote this comment.

Comment: @jazzurro yes, it appears I have, nice catch. In the current version if you remove the `if (is.null(l[[ii]])) next` line it should work. the original is [here](https://github.com/raredd/rawr/commit/b077d91fa107cb9ce651c0fca296dff8447608dc#diff-cbb7235afee10c3646161358a7655b0a) which doesn't include that line. I should add a logical to skip null elements or not

Comment: @rawr Thanks for that. I look forward to using an updated version soon!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to go with "use a version of `rapply` doesn't doesn't have weird behaviour with `NULL`".  This is the simplest implementation I can think of:

```
simple_rapply <- function(x, fn)
{
  if(is.list(x))
  {
    lapply(x, simple_rapply, fn)
  } else
  {
    fn(x)
  }
}
```

(`rawr::rapply2`, as mentioned in the comments by @rawr is a more sophisticated attempt.)

Now I can do the replacement using

```
simple_rapply(l, function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x)
```

Answer (score 11):

This is what William Dunlap suggested in 2010 when this question was asked on Rhelp:

```
replaceInList <- function (x, FUN, ...) 
  {
      if (is.list(x)) {
          for (i in seq_along(x)) {
              x[i] <- list(replaceInList(x[[i]], FUN, ...))
          }
          x
      }
      else FUN(x, ...)
  }
 replaceInList(l, function(x)if(is.null(x))NA else x)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a hack, but as far as hacks go, I think I'm somewhat happy with it.

```
lna <- eval(parse(text = gsub("NULL", "NA", deparse(l))))

str(lna)
#> List of 3
#> $ : logi NA
#> $ : num 1
#> $ :List of 3
#> ..$ : num 2
#> ..$ : logi NA
#> ..$ :List of 2
#> .. ..$ : num 3
#> .. ..$ : logi NA
```

**Update:**

If for some reason you needed `"NULL"` as a character entry in the list (corner case, much?) you can still use the above hack since it replaces the contents of the string, not the quotes, thus it just requires another step

```
l2 <- list(
  NULL,
  1,
  list(
    2,
    "NULL",
    list(
      3,
      NULL
    )
  )
)

lna2   <- eval(parse(text = gsub("NULL", "NA", deparse(l2))))
lna2_2 <- eval(parse(text = gsub('\\"NA\\"', '\"NULL\"', deparse(lna2))))

str(lna2_2)
#> List of 3
#> $ : logi NA
#> $ : num 1
#> $ :List of 3
#> ..$ : num 2
#> ..$ : chr "NULL"
#> ..$ :List of 2
#> .. ..$ : num 3
#> .. ..$ : logi NA
```

Comment: That's a very nice hack, but I worry about the dark magic in `eval`.  So the example is fine, but a string named `"NULL"` will confuse this.

Comment: Absolutely. Is that of concern to your use-case? Is that terrible practice to begin with?

Comment: It's kind of amusing to see this effort to convert R to a macro-processor. Not "bad", just amusing.

Comment: Trying out what would happen with the string "NULL", the quotes are untouched, so really you just need a second step... Editing.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Another evil corner case: The second version breaks if one of the names of the elements is `"NA"`. (That name gets converted to `"NULL"`.

Comment: @42- I think it is bad. And (depending on the content of the list) potentially extremely inefficient. Just imagine deparsing/parsing a list containing some large objects.

Comment: @Roland "bad" is maybe a little harsh.  This is a decent solution for the use case where you have a specific list that you want to process.  For a very large list, or a general list where you don't know the contents, it isn't suitable.

Comment: I'm not doubting for a moment that this is a poorer solution than using a better version of `rapply`. My answer is aimed at the question as posed (and works just fine for that), not numerous "but if"s that follow (especially ones that involve `"NA"` and `"NULL"` as plausible scenarios).

Answer (score 5):

I wrapped the replacement inside the sapply, which makes it more readable/understandable to me, albeit less general.

```
 replace_null <- function(x) {
  lapply(x, function(x) {
    if (is.list(x)){
      replace_null(x)
      } else{
        if(is.null(x)) NA else(x)
      } 
    })
}

replace_null(l)
```

Comment: Instead of `sapply` with `simplify = FALSE` just use `lapply`. You should also avoid `ifelse`.

Comment: @shayaa Using `ifelse` rather than `if` and `else` means that you'll have problems for non-vector inputs.  Try including a data.frame or a formula as one element of the list.

Comment: I get it; and it provides no vectorization benefits anyways, since it's not as if one of these list elements can be `c(1,NULL,1)` because the vector will just remove that element. I suppose that writing `if(is.null(x)) NA else(x)` just seemed clunkier to me. I will edit nonetheless

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done with `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package. Below are a few different ways we could replace the `NULL` elements in a nested list by `NA` values:

```r
library(rrapply)

l <- list(
    NULL,
    1,
    list(
        2,
        NULL,
        list(
            3,
            NULL
        )
    )
)

## replace NULL by NA using only f
rrapply(l, f = function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x, how = "replace")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]][[2]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[3]][[3]]
#> [[3]][[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[3]][[3]][[2]]
#> [1] NA

## replace NULL by NA using condition argument
rrapply(l, condition = is.null, f = function(x) NA, how = "replace")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]][[2]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[3]][[3]]
#> [[3]][[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[3]][[3]][[2]]
#> [1] NA

## replace NULL by NA using condition and deflt arguments 
rrapply(l, condition = Negate(is.null), deflt = NA, how = "list")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]][[2]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[3]][[3]]
#> [[3]][[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[3]][[3]][[2]]
#> [1] NA
```

We can also prune the `NULL` elements from the list altogether by setting `how = "prune"`:

```
## keep only non-NULL elements
rrapply(l, condition = Negate(is.null), how = "prune")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [[2]][[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 3
```