# Extracting to a data frame from a JSON generated multi-level list with occasional missing elements

Tags: r, purrr

I'm pulling soccer data through an API - the resulting JSON is returned as a list; `dput` example below:

```
list(list(id = 10332894L, league_id = 8L, season_id = 12962L, 
aggregate_id = NULL, venue_id = 201L, localteam_id = 51L, 
visitorteam_id = 27L, weather_report = list(code = "drizzle", 
    temperature = list(temp = 53.92, unit = "fahrenheit"), 
    clouds = "90%", humidity = "87%", wind = list(speed = "12.75 m/s", 
        degree = 200L)), attendance = 25098L, leg = "1/1", 
deleted = FALSE, referee = list(data = list(id = 15267L, 
    common_name = "L. Probert", fullname = "Lee Probert", 
    firstname = "Lee", lastname = "Probert"))), list(id = 10332895L, 
league_id = 8L, season_id = 12962L, aggregate_id = NULL, 
venue_id = 340L, localteam_id = 251L, visitorteam_id = 78L, 
weather_report = list(code = "drizzle", temperature = list(
    temp = 50.07, unit = "fahrenheit"), clouds = "90%", humidity = "93%", 
    wind = list(speed = "6.93 m/s", degree = 160L)), attendance = 22973L, 
leg = "1/1", deleted = FALSE, referee = list(data = list(
    id = 15273L, common_name = "M. Oliver", fullname = "Michael Oliver", 
    firstname = "Michael", lastname = "Oliver"))))
```

I'm extracting using a for loop at the moment - the reprex shows 2 top level list items when there are hundreds in the full data.  The main drawback of using a loop is that there are sometimes missing values which cause the loop to stop. I'd like to move this to `purrr` but am struggling to extract 2nd level nested items using `at_depth` or `modify_depth`. There are also nests inside nests which really adds to the complexity.

The end-state should be a tidy data frame - from this data the df will only have 2 rows but will have many columns each representing an item, no matter where that item is nested in this list. If something's missing then it should be an `NA` value.

The ideal scenario for a solution, even though it may be inelegant is that there's a data frame per level / nested item produced that can then be bound together later.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1: Replace `NULL` with `NA` using community wiki's function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950005/how-to-manipulate-null-elements-in-a-nested-list)

```
simple_rapply <- function(x, fn)
{
  if(is.list(x))
  {
    lapply(x, simple_rapply, fn)
  } else
  {
    fn(x)
  }
}    
non.null.l <- simple_rapply(l, function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x)
```

Step2:

```
library(purrr)
map_df(map(non.null.l,unlist),bind_rows)
```

Comment: Thanks - that did a really good job, but some of the items in the nested-sub-lists weren't extracted. So if you look at the sub-list `my_list[[1]][["weather_report"]]` , there's a column been created for `weather` but the value is from `my_list[[1]][["weather_report"]][["code"]]` and the further sublists aren't unpacked, nor are the items included at the same level as `code`. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @nycrefugee it's my pleasure to help. I think foldel's procedure designed for two levels list, not for a multilevel list and that what caused the issue in the final df. Please check if there is anything went wrong again. Finally, we take this path because of `aggregate_id` as its `NULL` and `unlist` will drop it, if you don't need it then you can do step2 directly. Thanks