# Converting a 1 level list with irregular items to a data frame

Tags: r, list, purrr

I'm looking for simple solution to the above. I seem to run into this problem frequently when APIs return JSON which is subsequently converted to a list.

Reprex data:

```
result_head <- list(list(name = "JEFFREY", gender = "male", probability = 1L, 
count = 932L), list(name = "Jan", gender = "male", probability = 0.6, 
count = 1663L), list(name = "Elquis", gender = NULL), list(
name = "ELQUIS", gender = NULL), list(name = "Francisco", 
gender = "male", probability = 1L, count = 1513L))
```

The task is, as simply as possible to convert this to a 5 row data frame. Given the items within each list element are irregular, `NA`s will need to introduced for missing items similar to how `bind_rows` works when stacking data frames with irregular columns.

What I've tried:

```
map_dfr(result, bind_rows)

do.call(bind_rows, result_head)

flatten(result_head)

bind_rows(flatten(result_head))
```

I asked a similar question here:
[Extracting to a data frame from a JSON generated multi-level list with occasional missing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010404/extracting-to-a-data-frame-from-a-json-generated-multi-level-list-with-occasiona)

... but the solution is totally over-engineered for a less complex list.

I'd like a solution that is hopefully elegant as possible - I run into this kind of operation so often and yet there doesn't seem to be a consistent way of doing this with few levels of function abstraction.

I realise questions around this may have already been asked and I may have missed something, but there doesn't seem to be a consistent and simple way of tackling what seems a common problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option with `map` after `flatten`ing and converting to `tibble`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(result_head, ~ flatten(.x) %>%
                as_tibble)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  name      gender probability count
#  <chr>     <chr>        <dbl> <int>
#1 JEFFREY   male           1     932
#2 Jan       male           0.6  1663
#3 Elquis    <NA>          NA      NA
#4 ELQUIS    <NA>          NA      NA
#5 Francisco male           1    1513
```

Or as @G.Groethendieck mentioned in the comments

```
map_dfr(result_head, flatten)
```

Comment: or just `library(purrr); map_dfr(result_head, flatten)`

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest why does the syntax of map call for .x and instead of x? Likewise in the documentation it mentions .x and .f.

Comment: @nycrefugee  It could be to prevent any clash with other identifiers named as 'x'.  It is less likely to have a object named as `.x`

Answer (score 2):

```
library(purrr) # transpose and map_if
library(rlist) # list.stack

result_head <- list(
  list(name = "JEFFREY", gender = "male", probability = 1L, count = 932L), 
  list(name = "Jan", gender = "male", probability = 0.6, count = 1663L), 
  list(name = "Elquis", gender = NULL), 
  list(name = "ELQUIS", gender = NULL), 
  list(name = "Francisco", gender = "male", probability = 1L, count = 1513L)
)

list.stack(transpose(
  lapply(transpose(result_head), function(y) map_if(y, is.null, function(x) NA))
))
```

---

```
       name gender probability count
1   JEFFREY   male         1.0   932
2       Jan   male         0.6  1663
3    Elquis   <NA>          NA    NA
4    ELQUIS   <NA>          NA    NA
5 Francisco   male         1.0  1513
```