# Using the right combinations of purrr::map functions to create a df from a multi level list

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have a reasonably complicated multi-level list:

```
    my_list <- list(list(id = 36L, name = "Marathonbet", odds = list(data = list(
list(label = "1", value = "1.25", dp3 = "1.250", american = "-400", 
    winning = TRUE, handicap = NULL, total = NULL, bookmaker_event_id = "6938899", 
    last_update = list(date = "2018-08-12 13:12:23.000000", 
        timezone_type = 3L, timezone = "UTC")), list(label = "2", 
    value = "13.75", dp3 = "13.750", american = "1275", winning = FALSE, 
    handicap = NULL, total = NULL, bookmaker_event_id = "6938899", 
    last_update = list(date = "2018-08-12 13:12:23.000000", 
        timezone_type = 3L, timezone = "UTC")), list(label = "X", 
    value = "7.00", dp3 = "7.000", american = "600", winning = FALSE, 
    handicap = NULL, total = NULL, bookmaker_event_id = "6938899", 
    last_update = list(date = "2018-08-12 13:12:23.000000", 
        timezone_type = 3L, timezone = "UTC"))))), list(id = 7L, 
name = "888Sport", odds = list(data = list(list(label = "1", 
    value = "1.23", dp3 = "1.230", american = "-435", winning = TRUE, 
    handicap = NULL, total = NULL, bookmaker_event_id = "1004746417", 
    last_update = list(date = "2018-08-12 13:12:23.000000", 
        timezone_type = 3L, timezone = "UTC")), list(label = "2", 
    value = "12.50", dp3 = "12.500", american = "1150", winning = FALSE, 
    handicap = NULL, total = NULL, bookmaker_event_id = "1004746417", 
    last_update = list(date = "2018-08-12 13:12:23.000000", 
        timezone_type = 3L, timezone = "UTC")), list(label = "X", 
    value = "6.50", dp3 = "6.500", american = "550", winning = FALSE, 
    handicap = NULL, total = NULL, bookmaker_event_id = "1004746417", 
    last_update = list(date = "2018-08-12 13:12:23.000000", 
        timezone_type = 3L, timezone = "UTC"))))), list(id = 9L, 
name = "BetFred", odds = list(data = list(list(label = "1", 
    value = "1.30", dp3 = NULL, american = NULL, winning = TRUE, 
    handicap = NULL, total = NULL, bookmaker_event_id = "1085457020", 
    last_update = list(date = "2018-07-26 08:30:19.000000", 
        timezone_type = 3L, timezone = "UTC")), list(label = "2", 
    value = "9.00", dp3 = NULL, american = NULL, winning = FALSE, 
    handicap = NULL, total = NULL, bookmaker_event_id = "1085457020", 
    last_update = list(date = "2018-07-26 08:30:19.000000", 
        timezone_type = 3L, timezone = "UTC")), list(label = "X", 
    value = "5.50", dp3 = NULL, american = NULL, winning = FALSE, 
    handicap = NULL, total = NULL, bookmaker_event_id = "1085457020", 
    last_update = list(date = "2018-07-26 08:30:19.000000", 
        timezone_type = 3L, timezone = "UTC"))))))
```

I can use a combination of `map` and `map_depth` to eliminate levels of nesting, but I'm struggling then to bind those levels into a data frame and preserve all the data.  For example - at level `my_list[[1]][["odds"]][["data"]]` there are three sub lists. When converting that level to a df I only end up with one row of data when there should be 3.

What I would like to do is convert this entire list to a data frame, where the common elements across sublists such as:
`my_list[[1]][["odds"]][["data"]][[1]][["bookmaker_event_id"]]` &
`my_list[[2]][["odds"]][["data"]][[1]][["bookmaker_event_id"]]`

appear in the same column in the resulting df.

It seems like a easy thing to achieve, but I either end up with missing rows of data or `Error: Argument 1 must have names`. The resulting data frame from this test list should have 9 rows and around 13 columns.

I'd like to use the `map` family of functions and avoid any loops please.

Comment: from JSON - I'm using `httr` with an external API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with a `lapply` solution, because I'm not very familiar with `map`:

```
DF <- bind_rows(lapply(my_list,function(ll){ #lapply over the list and bind result to tibble
  id <- ll[['id']] #Extract id
  name <- ll[['name']] #Extract name

  #clean up date and unlist sublists
  ll <- lapply(ll[['odds']][['data']],function(il)
  {
    il$last_update <- unlist(il$last_update)
    return(unlist(il))
  })

  df <- as_tibble(do.call(rbind,ll)) #bind the sublists and generate tibble
  df$id <- rep(id,nrow(df)) #add id
  df$name <- rep(name,nrow(df)) #add name
  return(df) #return df
}))

DF

A tibble: 9 x 11
  label value dp3    american winning bookmaker_event~ last_update.date last_update.tim~ last_update.tim~    id name 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <int> <chr>
1 1     1.25  1.250  -400     TRUE    6938899          2018-08-12 13:1~ 3                UTC                 36 Mara~
2 2     13.75 13.750 1275     FALSE   6938899          2018-08-12 13:1~ 3                UTC                 36 Mara~
3 X     7.00  7.000  600      FALSE   6938899          2018-08-12 13:1~ 3                UTC                 36 Mara~
4 1     1.23  1.230  -435     TRUE    1004746417       2018-08-12 13:1~ 3                UTC                  7 888S~
5 2     12.50 12.500 1150     FALSE   1004746417       2018-08-12 13:1~ 3                UTC                  7 888S~
6 X     6.50  6.500  550      FALSE   1004746417       2018-08-12 13:1~ 3                UTC                  7 888S~
7 1     1.30  NA     NA       TRUE    1085457020       2018-07-26 08:3~ 3                UTC                  9 BetF~
8 2     9.00  NA     NA       FALSE   1085457020       2018-07-26 08:3~ 3                UTC                  9 BetF~
9 X     5.50  NA     NA       FALSE   1085457020       2018-07-26 08:3~ 3                UTC                  9 BetF~
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @shayaa's function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950005/how-to-manipulate-null-elements-in-a-nested-list) to replace Null with NA since `unlist` and `flatten` ignored NULL

```
replace_null <- function(x) {
lapply(x, function(x) {
if (is.list(x)){
  replace_null(x)
  } else{
    if(is.null(x)) NA else(x)
  } 
})
}
```

Then use `tibble` and `purrr::flatten`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
my_list %>% {
tibble(
  id=map_dbl(.,'id'),
  name=map_chr(.,'name'),
  odds=map(.,'odds') %>% map(. ,'data') %>% map(.,.%>% map(replace_null) %>% map_df(flatten))
  #odds=map(.,~.x[['odds']][['data']] %>% map(replace_null) %>% map_df(flatten))
  )} %>% 
  unnest(odds)

  # A tibble: 9 x 13
        id name        label value dp3    american winning handicap total bookmaker_event_~ date                    timezone_type timezone
      <dbl> <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <lgl>   <lgl>    <lgl> <chr>             <chr>                           <int> <chr>   
  1    36 Marathonbet 1     1.25  1.250  -400     TRUE    NA       NA    6938899           2018-08-12 13:12:23.00~             3 UTC     
  2    36 Marathonbet 2     13.75 13.750 1275     FALSE   NA       NA    6938899           2018-08-12 13:12:23.00~             3 UTC     
  3    36 Marathonbet X     7.00  7.000  600      FALSE   NA       NA    6938899           2018-08-12 13:12:23.00~             3 UTC     
  4     7 888Sport    1     1.23  1.230  -435     TRUE    NA       NA    1004746417        2018-08-12 13:12:23.00~             3 UTC     
  5     7 888Sport    2     12.50 12.500 1150     FALSE   NA       NA    1004746417        2018-08-12 13:12:23.00~             3 UTC     
  6     7 888Sport    X     6.50  6.500  550      FALSE   NA       NA    1004746417        2018-08-12 13:12:23.00~             3 UTC     
  7     9 BetFred     1     1.30  NA     NA       TRUE    NA       NA    1085457020        2018-07-26 08:30:19.00~             3 UTC     
  8     9 BetFred     2     9.00  NA     NA       FALSE   NA       NA    1085457020        2018-07-26 08:30:19.00~             3 UTC     
  9     9 BetFred     X     5.50  NA     NA       FALSE   NA       NA    1085457020        2018-07-26 08:30:19.00~             3 UTC
```

For more info see [this](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls02_map-extraction-advanced.html) purrr tutorial.