# unlist nested lists without losing Nulls

Tags: r

```
  dat=list(list(id = "T"), list(id = "T"), 
structure(list(NULL), names = NA_character_), list(id = "T"), 
list(id = "T"), list(id = "T"))

      unlist(dat)
```

I treid but did not work

```
    dat[sapply(dat, is.null)] <- NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78140564/12545041) by ThomasIsCoding with a list as above, where you do not have `NULL` at the top level and do not want to recursively unlist.

However, if either of these conditions are not satisfied then you can traverse the list, setting `NULL` to `NA`.

#### `tidyverse` approach

I like to use [`purrr::modify_tree()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/modify_tree.html) for operations like this, passing a function to apply to every leaf.

```r
dat |> 
    purrr::modify_tree(
        leaf = \(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x,
        post = unlist
    )
#   id   id <NA>   id   id   id 
#  "T"  "T"   NA  "T"  "T"  "T"
```

The `post` parameter is a function that is *applied on the way "up", i.e. after the leaves are transformed*.

#### base R approach

It feels as if you ought to be able to use [`base::rapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rapply.html) to recursively iterate. Unfortunately, it [ignores `NULL` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950005/how-to-manipulate-null-elements-in-a-nested-list/). We can instead write a recursive function:

```r
replace_null  <- function(x, repl = NA, is_node = is.list) {
    if(is_node(x)) return(lapply(x, replace_null))
    if(is.null(x)) repl else x # or in R 4.4:   x %||% repl
}
unlist(replace_null(dat))
#   id   id <NA>   id   id   id 
#  "T"  "T"   NA  "T"  "T"  "T"
```

The `is_node` parameter determines whether to recurse further, in the same way as the argument with the same name in `purrr::modify_tree()`.

#### The null coalescing operator `%||%`

Incidentally if you're using the current development version of R (to be released as 4.4) you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html).

> `L %||% R` newly in base is an expressive idiom for the phrases `if(!is.null(L)) L else R` or `if(is.null(L)) R else L`.

Here is an example of the difference of this approach when one of the top-level items is `NULL`.

```r
l  <- list(1, NULL)
unlist(l)
# [1] 1

dat |> 
    purrr::modify_tree(
        leaf = \(x) x %||% NA,
        post = unlist
    )
# [1]  1 NA
```

Comment: I think you can use `rrapply` as well, e.g., `rrapply::rrapply(dat, f = function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x), how = "unlist")`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding yes! There is an answer using `rrapply` now, which is a strong contender for the best approach in this case. I tend to use `rrapply` only if I need the special arguments like `.xname` or `.xsiblings`. I find the `purrr` API a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `recursive = FALSE` in `unlist`, e.g.,

```
> unlist(dat, recursive = FALSE)
$id
[1] "T"

$id
[1] "T"

$<NA>
NULL

$id
[1] "T"

$id
[1] "T"

$id
[1] "T"
```

Comment: This is definitely best in this case - but if one of the top level items is `NULL` you will lose it. Arguably, though, you shouldn't have `NULL` in a list and expect to be able to keep it after manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using `rrapply()` (package `rrapply`) to flatten the nested list to a single-level list preserving `NULL` values:

```
rrapply::rrapply(dat, how = "flatten")
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
#> 
#> $<NA>
#> NULL
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
```

This also preserves any `NULL`s at the top-level (or any other level) of the nested list:

```
dat <- list(
  test = NULL, 
  list(id = "T"), 
  list(id = "T"), 
  structure(list(NULL), names = NA_character_), 
  list(id = "T"), 
  list(id = "T"), 
  list(id = "T")
)

rrapply::rrapply(dat, how = "flatten")
#> $test
#> NULL
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
#> 
#> $<NA>
#> NULL
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] "T"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two `unlist`s with `replace` in between.

```
> unlist(replace((u1 <- unlist(dat, FALSE)), lengths(u1) == 0L, NA))
  id   id <NA>   id   id   id 
 "T"  "T"   NA  "T"  "T"  "T"
```