# Using rapply to replace NULL elements in a nested list

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation, purrr

I have the following list:

```r
my_list = list(list(NULL, '4'), NULL, 5)

str(my_list)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr "4"
#>  $ : NULL
#>  $ : num 5
```

I would like to learn how to replace the NULL elements with NA. Is it possible to do this using `rapply`? Here is my attempt:

```r
my_list = list(list(NULL, '4'), NULL, 5)

rapply(my_list, function(x) NA, how = "replace", classes = 'NULL')
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] "4"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 5
```

I would like rapply to replace `NULL` elements, hence I specified `classes = 'NULL'` and `how = 'replace'`. But as you can see in the output above, the `NULL` elements are not replaced.

I can achieve the desired output by recursively applying `purrr::modify` as follows:

```r
library(purrr)

my_list = list(list(NULL, '4', list('y', NULL)), NULL, 5)
str(my_list)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr "4"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "y"
#>   .. ..$ : NULL
#>  $ : NULL
#>  $ : num 5

replaceNULL <- function(x) {

  modify_if(x, is.list, replaceNULL, .else = ~ifelse(is.null(.), NA, .))

}
replaceNULL(my_list)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] "4"
#> 
#> [[1]][[3]]
#> [[1]][[3]][[1]]
#> [1] "y"
#> 
#> [[1]][[3]][[2]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>

However, I was wondering if someone could shed some light on why the `rapply` isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950005/how-to-manipulate-null-elements-in-a-nested-list/

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, I seemed to have missed that one when I searched for similar questions. I don't mind deleting mine but I was hoping someone could help me understand why the `rapply` wasn't working.

Comment: No need to delete. If you think the post answers your question I'll mark it as duplicate or else we can  keep it as open.

Comment: Cheers, the answers in the other post don't get into why the `rapply` failed so I'd prefer to keep this one open.

Comment: In the question linked by @Ronak Shah, there is also this link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170264/why-do-rapply-and-lapply-handle-null-differently